# 'I know the difference between right and wrong' what type of knowledge does this statement talk of?

Tags: epistemology

'I know the difference between right and wrong', which form of knowledge would suit this statement most?

1. Propositional/Factual Knowledge - Know that
2. Knowledge by Acquaintance - Know of
3. Ability/Practical Knowledge - Know how

likewise

'Do you know the way to San José?'

Is this statement speaking of knowledge by acquaintance or ability/practical knowledge or factual?

Comment: The claim expresses knowing what morality is (that is called normative ethics in academia). This type of claim has to do with universal knowledge (aka objective knowledge) which is distinct from scientific knowledge. Objective knowledge is CONSTANT & never changes value EVER. So an objective claim holds for infinite time. That is an objective truth stays true forever. Truths that can change value such as theories like evolution, relativity, etc are not objective. If a claim can be shown true on Monday and be false on Tuesday that is a CONTINGENT TRUTH. Objective truths hold more weight.

Answer (score 1):

If this is HW, I think th question contans a pittfall. I think the person that has deviced the exercice intends students to reason like this : what is right is what one has a duty to accomplish ( what is wrong is what people shouldn't do); action pertains to the practical realm; therefore, this is knowledge how. But, n fact, knowing what is right does not imply having the ability to do it.

---

- The expression " factual knowledge" may conceal an ambiguity.
- But, right and wrong are normative terms; they are not supposed to escribe what is actually happening, but what ought to happen / be the case . So, " that such and such action is right" is not a fact in the descriptive sense.
- So one may rather say that knowing that such and such action is right amounts to  propositional knowledge ; the expression is arguably better suited than " factual" knowledge.
- Also, the typology might be misleading. For  propositional knowledge can be  theoretical or practical ( inasmuch as it directs action). Practical propositional knowledge is not knowing-how.
- Knowing the difference between right and wrong is not necessarily being able to identify what falls under these concepts. If one admits that right and wrong are " norms" one can be acquainted with ( by some kind of intuition) then knowing-of is an acceptable answer.